# Why do T-SQL ranking values return nullable columns?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

When using the ranking functions of T-SQL, the column containing ranking values is nullable.

You can see this when creating a view of the result set:

```
CREATE VIEW v
AS 
  SELECT Name
    , ListPrice
    , RANK() OVER (ORDER BY ListPrice DESC) AS [Rank]
    , DENSE_RANK() OVER (ORDER BY ListPrice DESC) AS [DenseRank]
    , ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY ListPrice DESC) AS [RowNumber]
FROM Production.Product
```

Executing `sp_help` for this view indicates that the columns using ranking functions are nullable:

```
EXEC sp_help 'v'

Column_name   (...) | Nullable
---------------...-+------------+
...           (...) | ...
Rank          (...) | Yes
DenseRank     (...) | Yes
RowNumber     (...) | Yes
```

Which condition would cause a ranking function to return `NULL`?

Comment: AFAIK computed columns in Views aren't treated any differently from computed columns in base tables. [Some comments on that and nullability are at the bottom of this page.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191250.aspx)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Every computed/function based column in a view appears to be nullable. E.g.:

```
create view v1
as
    select OBJECT_ID,OBJECT_ID * 1 as obj2 from sys.objects
go
EXEC sp_help 'v1'
```

Indicates that `object_id` is not nullable but that `obj2` is, even though it's trivially observable that if `object_id` can never be null, nor can `obj2`.

The only way I know of (not sure if this is what you're really looking for) to force a column to appear to not be nullable, is to wrap it in an `ISNULL`:

```
create view v2
as
    select OBJECT_ID,ISNULL(OBJECT_ID * 1,0) as obj2 from sys.objects
go
EXEC sp_help 'v2'
```

Interestingly, this is one of the few places where you can't use `COALESCE` instead of `ISNULL`:

```
create view v3
as
    select OBJECT_ID,COALESCE(OBJECT_ID * 1,0) as obj2 from sys.objects
go
EXEC sp_help 'v3'
```

`v3` resembles `v1`.